# Linear Algebra, Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

State if a given map is a linear operator from V to W. Explain your answer.

$V=R^2$, $W =R^3$, $f(a,b)=(a−b+1,−a,b)$

This is what I have thus far...

$T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$

$T(αv) = αT(v)$

$R^2-->R^3$

$u=a1,b1$

$v=a2,b2$

$T(u+v)=T(a1,b1,a2,b2)=T(a1+a2,b1+b2)=(a1+a2-b1-b2+1,-a1-a2,b1+b2)$

$T(u)+T(v)=(a1-b1+1,-a1,b1)+(a2-b2+1,-a2,b2)$

Anyone know if this is right so far and what are the steps to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a workable aproach. You will have to continue the last line and add the vectors, and you'll see that the first term doesn't really match (you'll get $T(u)+T(v) = (a_1+a_2-b_1-b_2+2, ...) \ne (a_1+a_2-b_1-b_2+1, ...)$).

You've got a couple of errors in the last line though. When things gets messy it's important to be careful to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: I fixed it @skyking, hopefully that's better and makes more sense

Comment: Yes, to be clear the sense it makes is that $f$ is not linear because of the difference between $T(u)+T(v)$ and $T(u+v)$.

Comment: Yes thank you, I got to that conclusion when writing it on paper @skyking!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way, although your notation needs a lot of improvement.

You need to fix your expressions for $T(u)$ and $T(v)$, keep on simplifying $T(u)+T(v)$ and check whether or not it equals $T(u+v)$.

However there is an easy short cut: if $T(0)\ne0$ then $T$ is not linear.  Check it out.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot!